# API method to start VM in VMware Vsphere?

Tags: vmware

Are there any API methods to start, stop and snapshot VM using pyvmomi?

I  was able to get list of all VMs using provided sample code but there is no such sample code. Plus, i looked up method for same tasks, but documentation seems to be so complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on vSphere 6.5 or newer and trying to use the REST API: https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/423e512d-dda1-496f-9de3-851c28ca0814/0e3f6e0d-8d05-4f0c-887b-3d75d981bae5/VMware-vSphere-Automation-SDK-REST-6.7.0/docs/apidocs/operations/com/vmware/vcenter/vm/power.start-operation.html

```
POST https://{server}/rest/vcenter/vm/{vm}/power/start
```